# Find word in text and remove the text that contained the word

Tags: excel, text, split, formula

I've set of data that need to find certain word in text in excel, and if the text has this word, need to remove the whole text.

previously I was using text to column to do this, but the problem sometimes the position of the word is not same, such as have extra number. Kindly refer below for example.

example :

1. 1013-2329308 1013EFECTIVO0002046 0221901
2. 1013-3747097 1013EFECTIVO0002060 0123123
3. 1013-37274979 1013EFECTIVO00020615 0136659

What I'm trying to do is to find word EFECTIVO in text and the remove the text including before the text. In above example.

the final result will be like this.

1. 0221901
2. 0123123
3. 0136659

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems, you want to extract last word (space delimited) if found a specific word in full text.

Answer (score 1):

You may try-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EFECTIVO",A1)),TEXTAFTER(A1," ",-1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I've tested the formula however the value returned blank in my data.

Comment: @sephiroth Can you post a screenshot of your formula in sheet.

Comment: Done added the screenshot above.

Comment: What is your excel version? Do you have `TEXTAFTER()` function in your version?

Comment: Excel 365 version, yes i can use textafter function. I just noticed that i have extra space from 1013-2329308 1013EFECTIVO0002046 0221901  at then end of 0221901, how to make the formula detect that one?

Comment: Is that space or other special character?

Comment: space, i try replace the space in ctrl f, and it remove the space at the end of the sentences